# Finding out the dimension of the diagonal

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Consider the diagonal $D= \{(w,x,y)\in \mathbb{A}^{3n}:w=x=y\}$. We can work with field $k$, where $k$ is not necessarily closed, for example $\mathbb{R}$ (maybe let's just work with $k=\mathbb{R}$). We impose the Zariski topology on $\mathbb{A}^n=k^n$ (and on $k^{3n}$). Then how can we compute the dimension of $D$? The definition of dimension of a topological space $X$ is the following:

Let $X$ be a topological space. A chain of subsets of $X$ is a sequence $X_0\subset X_1 \dots... \subset X_n$ such that the $X_i$ are distinct. Such a chain is said to be of length $n$. The dimension of $X$ is the maximum of the lengths of chains of irreducible closed subsets of $X$.

In case $k= \mathbb{R}$, it seems that observing that $D= V(f)$ is probably relevant, where $$f(w,x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^n(w_i-x_i)^2+\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-y_i)^2+\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-z_i)^2.$$

> I expect the dimension to be $n$ but how do I prove it?

Secondly, let $W=\{(x,x,x)\in \mathbb{A}^n|\nabla g(x)=0\}$ for some homogenous polynomial $f$.

> If $g$ is non-singular (i.e. the Jacobian is not zero), what is the
> dimension of $W$?

I don't really know any algebraic geometry, so I would appreciate a hint or two. I have no clue as to which theorems are pertinent/useful at all, nor any intuition for dimension. Thanks!

Comment: Your variety is a linear subspace. Its dimension is the same as the one as vector space dimension, so it is $n$.

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez, could you please elaborate on your comment? Is it trivial: as in does it follow straight from the definition? Also, restated, are you saying that if $W$ is a $k-$vector subspace of say $k^n$ and also $W$ is an affine variety in $k^n$, then dimension of $W$ as a subspace is the same as the dimension of $W$ as a topological space under the Zariski topology?

Comment: Yes, I am saying that. Its proof can be done in several ways but the one I find simpler is using that $\dim X$ is equal to the dimension of the affine ring of $X$

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez,  Thanks for your comment. By any chance, do you have a hint for the second question?